How to add a Microsoft Office font (Aptos) in a Mosaico template
I have tried to add a Microsoft Office font, Aptos, in the Mosaico template "CiviVersafix" by changing the html template:
./civicrm/mosaico_tpl/CiviVersafix/template-CiviVersafix.html
as folllows:
@supports -ko-blockdefs {

face { label: Font; widget: select; options: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif=Arial|Aptos, Arial, sans-serif=Aptos|... }

I have also cleared up caches in CiviCRM, but with no lack, the new font Aptos added is not available.
Any idea what else should I be doing?
Thank you in advance!
